# How can I multiply a float and u64 in Rust?

Tags: rust

I want to have a nice way to show sol amounts in my code:

use anchor_lang::solana_program::native_token::LAMPORTS_PER_SOL;

const REWARD: u64 = LAMPORTS_PER_SOL * 0.1; // 0.1 SOL

I am getting this error:
help: the trait `Mul<{float}>` is not implemented for `u64`

How would I solve that in Rust?

Answer (score 1):

Well this works:

```
const CHEST_REWARD: u64 = LAMPORTS_PER_SOL / 10; // 0.1 SOL
```

Maybe good enough :D

Answer (score 1):

I understand that the data types they handle are variables, so this function could help you to convert the lamport expressed in u64 to SOL expressed in decimal:

```
fn lamports_to_sol(lamport: u64) -> f64 {
        let sol: f64 = lamport as f64;
        return (sol / 1000000000.0) as f64
    }
let amount: u64 = 1256541200;
```